# ruby and accdb (ms access)

Tags: ruby, ms-access, windows-xp

If I have a base windows xp system, ruby and an ms access 2007 file (say c:/foo/bar.accdb) file, what's the least intrusive method for reading that .accdb file.

- What needs to be installed on the xp system.
- What is the specific connection string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you started. Of course, you'll need to modify some of the values like; path, filename, SQLstatement, etc.

MDB file (Access 2003 format and older) using the Jet engine

```
require 'win32ole'
connection = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Connection')
connection.Open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                 Data Source=c:\path\filename.mdb')
```

ACCDB file (Access 2007 format and newer) using the ACE engine

```
require 'win32ole'
connection = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Connection')
connection.Open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                 Data Source=c:\path\filename.accdb')
```

To execute a SQL query that doesn't return data use:

```
connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Table VALUES ('Data1', 'Data2');")
```

To perform a query that returns a recordset:

```
recordset = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Recordset')
recordset.Open(SQLstatement, connection)
```

Comment: I needed to use:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: Yup, that uses the new version of the Access database engine, ACE, as opposed to the old Jet engine.

Answer (score 7):

You may use the Ruby library Sequel (http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) , it has ADO adapter

Answer (score 3):

You could use ADO via Ruby's *win32ole* library.

Complete details and code can be found [here](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ADO then you will find the ADO libraries already installed on a Windows XP box (otherwise distribute MDAC). Then all you need is the ACE dlls plus its OLE DB Provider, available for free from the Microsoft Download Center:

[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891)

Answer (score 1):

As this blog post explains it ([Ruby on Windows: Using Ruby & ADO to Work with MS Access Databases](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html), you can use ADO to connect to the MS Access 2007 database.

Answer (score 1):

If Sequel and ADO don't work even after adding the 2007 Office system driver: Check to see if you are running 32-bit or the 64-bit version of Ruby.  I had to bump my version down to 32-bit to get things to work correctly.