# Accessing MS Access from ruby in windows7

Tags: ruby, ms-access

I want to access MS Access database from my ruby. Am using window platform. Could anyone help me out of this??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120225/ruby-and-accdb-ms-access

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the win32ole library  This site shows you how to connect to access 2003 database http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html, if you are using a newer version of office you might have to change a few things

Comment: The Ruby on Windows blog is an awesome resource for using the `win32ole` library with Office.

Comment: I agree though its been sometime since he has posted to it.