# Accessing Msacess database using shoes ruby framework

Tags: ruby, ms-access, shoes

Could any one tell me how to access ms acess database using shoes(ruby framework). I want to create a form in shoes could anyone help me out of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120225/ruby-and-accdb-ms-access

Comment: But i couldnt find win32ole in the repository, could any one help on this??

Comment: It should be included with ruby by default. Just `require` it.