# Edit Access database with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to edit (make new records, add and change content, etc.) an Access database with Ruby? If yes, how?

If it is not possible, does anyone knows a good alternative to store information from HTML forms?

Comment: PostgreSQL? MySQL? Beside that you wanna take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120225/ruby-and-accdb-ms-access

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to have this running on a Windows box then yes, it is *possible* to manipulate an Access database from Ruby via ODBC or OLEDB (ADO). However, the Access Database Engine is a poor choice for a web application's back-end database. In fact, "Microsoft strongly recommends against using Access in web applications." (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database)).

If you plan to implement this on a non-Windows machine then I would recommend that you simply don't bother messing around with Access ODBC. You *might* be able to get JRuby and the UCanAccess JDBC driver to update the Access database, but that would also not be a good choice for a web back-end.

You really should investigate other more suitable back-end databases for your web application: Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, etc., etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can use all kinds of databases with Ruby - including an Access database, using the Ruby DBI module.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_database_access.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with using an access-database with ASP and Ruby (some projects I took over).
One advise: don't do it, there is trouble all the way.
If you intend to keep it simple and small and want to have a transposable/portable database without asking too much about speed and size, you could use SQLite. For all other purposes, try the ones Gord suggests.

If you insist on Access the use [sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/), it's an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) which takes the burden away from transgerrring database-data to objects and vice-versa and as a benefit, you can change the database you use later on with just a couple of lines to change.